# App crashes in iPhone simulator when button is pressed. Xcode 3.2.5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

My app is a tab bar application. There are two tabs at the bottom and an outlet on the first tab with a button that leads to a new window. When I build the code in xcode, it succeeds. When I launch the app in the simulator and click the button leading to the new window, it crashes the app. This is my code for the "FirstViewController" and the "GuitarBrandsViewController"

***FirstViewController.h-***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GuitarBrandsViewController.h"


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    FirstViewController *firstViewController;

    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet UIWindow *GuitarBrands;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

-(IBAction)gotoGuitarBrands;

@end
```

***FirstViewController.m***

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"


@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize window;

-(IBAction)gotoGuitarBrands{

    GuitarBrandsViewController *screen = [[GuitarBrandsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];
}
```

***GuitarBrandsViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface GuitarBrandsViewController : UIViewController {
    GuitarBrandsViewController *guitarBrandsViewController;
    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet UIWindow *Main;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
-(IBAction)gotoMain;

@end
```

***GuitarBrandsViewController.m***

```
#import "GuitarBrandsViewController.h"

@implementation GuitarBrandsViewController
@synthesize window;

-(IBAction)gotoMain{

    FirstViewController *screen = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
    [screen release];
}
```

Comment: That's a good example of why I don't use interface builder. It is a pain to ask for help... there is no way for us to tell if your controls are correctly linked to your selectors...

Comment: And what errors are displayed by xcode?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are creating the GuitarBrandsViewController using Interface Builder as the code in the class itself would not work on it's own.

However, when you initialize GuitarBrandsViewController, you don't pass the NIB so you allocate the Controlling Class without the actual NIB information from IB.

Instead of

```
 GuitarBrandsViewController *screen = [[GuitarBrandsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Use

```
GuitarBrandsViewController *screen = [[GuitarBrandsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GuitarBrandsViewController.xib" bundle:nil];
```

Adjust the nib name to the name of the actual nib you use.